# insert content in a specific place inside an existing file python

Tags: python, file

I am trying to append the parameters passed to a function to a specific place in an existing text file.
txt file:

```
query{
text:"",
source_language:"",
target_language:"",
},
data_type:[16],
params{
client:"xyz"
}
```

python:

```
def function(text,source_language,target_language):
     f = open("file.txt", "w");
     f.write( 'text:' + text + '\n' )
     f.write( 'source_language:' + source_language + '\n' )
     f.write( 'target_language:' + target_language + '\n' )
     f.close()
```

But, its not working. Is there a way to append the parameters directly into the file including `" "` and `,`. I am trying to add just the parameters into the existing file with data at the specified position.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you append to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file)

Comment: @VikasDamodar The file content has too many syntax issues to be valid JSON.

Comment: Why not use `'a'` instead of `'w'`?

Comment: I have a solution, just did this for another question, will be back soon with proper solution you are requesting!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

In revision to your comments, considering that this is only being applied to the example above and need only to alter those specific three lines, this will accomplish the task (included `if location:` in case you don't match keyword it won't erase your file by `open('w')`

```
def change_text(new_text):
    content[1] = list(content[1])
    y = list(new_text)
    content[1] = content[1][:6] + y  + content[1][-2:]
    content[1] = ''.join(content[1])

def change_source_l(new_source_l):
    content[2] = list(content[2])
    y = list(new_source_l)
    content[2] = content[2][:17] + y  + content[2][-2:]
    content[2] = ''.join(content[2])

def change_target_l(new_target_l):
    content[3] = list(content[3])
    y = list(new_target_l)
    content[3] = content[3][:17] + y  + content[3][-2:]
    content[3] = ''.join(content[3])

filename = open('query.txt', 'r')
content = filename.read()
content = content.split()
filename.close()

name = open('query.txt', 'w')

change_text('something')
change_source_l('this')
change_target_l('that')

name.write('\n'.join(content))
name.close()
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/LPTHW$ cat query.txt 
> query{
> text:"something",
> source_language:"this",
> target_language:"that",
> },
> data_type:[16],
> params{
> client:"xyz"
> ```

Comment: Hi Vash, I just want the three input parameters given, to get attached between the double quotes mentioned in the file. Every time, the file should get overwritten.

Comment: Okay so instead of inserting you want to replace the entire line as in `text:"",` will become `text:"some_text"`,? instead of adding to the already blank entry `"",` and that goes for all three variables you described

Comment: Can we assume that the lines we are exchanging are always as shown in order `text:, source_language:, and target_language` to say is this specific for this is example or has to work with different parameters and locations?

Comment: I didn't get the output I wanted for the above code. Yes, the lines are to be in order. I don't want the entire content replaced, just content written over inside the double quotes every time new parameters are passed.

Comment: Okay not home I can do that though

Comment: still there I think I got what you need!

Answer (score -1):

Open file in `r+` mode 
Use `.seek` method from Python file I/O and then write your content.

Comment: This will not insert content into a file. Rather, it will overwrite the existing content so you'll end up with corrupted file content.

Comment: Thanks, this is something that i was looking for, but I can't seem to wrap my mind as to how to insert it inside the double quotes using seek. Any suggestion?